# How to get True File ID

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

By "True" I mean like its specific ID, i read somewhere on the internet a while back that you can get a file specific ID that only exists for that file, that way you are able to differentiate it from files that have the same name or other identical values.

**EXAMPLE**

Two pictures of a flower are uploaded, the first one is called `Flower1.png` but the second one is also called `Flower1.png`, they are both uploaded at the same time and are the same size ETC (Farfetched I know) but the images consists of two different images.

im thinking it will be along the context of `$_FILES['upload']['UID']` or something i just cant find it.

If anyone know what the name of this is id really appreciate it!

Comment: there is nothing such as UID in `$_FILES`.. if same name file been uploaded then latest will be replaced by older if any other condition is not applied. better to rename the file (prefix with timestamp ) while uploading

Comment: I know that there is no such thing as UID, and I am aware I could easily prefix timestamp but that's not what im asking.

Comment: Are you by chance referring to the **random file name** generated automatically by PHP when you upload a file? If that's the case, it's right there in `$_FILES`. You simply cannot have to objects with the same path in any file system.

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for the file [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). In `php` you can use this function `fileinode` ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileinode.php)).

```
fileinode($filename)
```

Comment: Please note that inodes are a low level feature of Unix file systems. If your PHP code relies on that, you won't be able to develop on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could compute a hash (maybe [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)) of the file and compare the hash with another file's hash.

Example (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php):

```
$hash_of_file1 = md5_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']);
$hash_of_file2 = md5_file($_FILES['file2']['tmp_name']);

if ($hash_of_file1 == $hash_of_file2) {
  // contents are the same
} else {
  // contents are not the same
}
```